# What is API? Is it some code or only URL part?

Tags: node.js, api

I'm just started learning what is API. I've go through some documentation, post but still I didn't get it all.

I'm confused in, is API is just about code or just only url part ?

What is difference between URL and API.

When someone want to build API in their project what they have to do ?
I mean did they write some code or just only make some url ?

Like in express.js when I write some end point I write it

```
app.get("/user/id",(req,res)=>{
    //some stuff...
}
```

So here it mean that this is my API or what is it ?

I'm very confused in API. Please explain it.

Comment: API is anything that a consumer can use. If you're doing a REST API, then it would take form of a URL. But the API can also be the methods exposed by an object, so entirely programmatic. There may or may not be code that does stuff when you call the API. Although, the expectations is that you'd get *something*, even if it's a fake hard-coded response. At any rate, "API" is one of the terms that is not actually very useful because it's very broad. Anything you can call to get some work done can be classed as API. `Number.parseInt()` can be considered part of the vanilla JS API.

Comment: @VLAZ can you explain me in the context of node.js

Comment: No, because "API" is not specific to anything. It's an extremely generic term that can encompass basically anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia page is quite good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API

There's different kinds of APIs. The one you are probably thinking about is the 'Web API', also mentioned on this page.

Quote:

> In computing, an application programming interface (API) is an interface that defines interactions between multiple software applications or mixed hardware-software intermediaries.[1] It defines the kinds of calls or requests that can be made, how to make them, the data formats that should be used, the conventions to follow, etc. It can also provide extension mechanisms so that users can extend existing functionality in various ways and to varying degrees.[2] An API can be entirely custom, specific to a component, or designed based on an industry-standard to ensure interoperability. Through information hiding, APIs enable modular programming, allowing users to use the interface independently of the implementation.

Comment: Can you please explain API in the node.js context

Comment: There is no difference in node.js vs other contexts. Try to ask a more specific questions that's not "What is an API".